# Android - Launch multiple methods in others Activities

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

I'm really new to Android.

I have a fitness app where the user can change it's gym. There are several activities where **the content depends on the user's gym**. 
One activity will show the workouts of the gym, another the athletes of the gym, etc...

> What I would like, is to **update all of these activities when the user
>   change it's gym**.

I know how to do that in iOS, I just need to add an observer `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver()`, but I really don't know how to do that for android.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: your approach is wrong. you have to use fragments instead of activities for similar work. and you have to eeload data once yser changes the settings. Observer for small tasks are not recommended.

Comment: Share some piece of code. What do you mean by "the user change it's gym" ?

Comment: @LAD if that has to be done using activities (which he must not) then the problem is much simpler to solve. Store the current gym details in SharedPref and load appropriate gym in onCreare or onResume depending in the usage. Even in the worst case where programmers end up stacking activities as if they are fragments, onResume will be called giving chance to check and refresh data. Another reason of not using listeners for this kind of task is the invitation to memory leaks associated with listeners holding the activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, according to Google your app should contain only one entry point, in other words one `Activity`, and have `Fragments` to represent contents of application.

Second of all, for solution to your problem you could use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). It has `onSharedPreferencesChangeListener();` which could be used to listen for updates of information (e.g. GYM name, your custom user permissions, user role, etc.). When something changes in `SharedPreferences` you notify all dependent objects of application to change their information accordingly by using [Observer pattern](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-design-patterns-the-observer-pattern--cms-28963) (P.S. can use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) for that). You could also implement `SharedPreferences` change listener in all the `Fragments` and updated their data there.

If, for whatever reason, you want to stick with using multiple `Activities` in your application, you could still use `SharedPreferences`, but instead of listening to changes, you just read preference values in `Activity` `onCreate();` method and create content accordingly (change item visibility, color, etc.).

---

That's one of the approaches. Hope this puts you in the right direction. Good luck :)

Comment: "according to Google your app should contain only one entry point, in other words one Activity" Do you have a reference for that?  I see differently [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/intro-activities), "Most apps contain multiple screens, which means they comprise multiple activities. Typically, one activity in an app is specified as the main activity, which is the first screen to appear when the user launches the app. "

Comment: Yes, I do. **Quote with link:** [with a focus on making a single-Activity app the preferred architecture](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1)

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful read. May be worth adding the link to the answer too though.

Comment: I would if it was describing something specific, but the article is too broad to represent something useful for this answer. :)

Comment: I use Activities but with the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag. Shoud I use the observer pattern though ?

Comment: Observer pattern is just an old tool, because of that I wouldnt use ot if I were you. What I would do tho, is to implement SharedPreference listeners in all of your Activities and run custom refresh logic in them. Thats just one of the ways tho, I am sure you can Google some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) might help you with this, specifically [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) which is an Observable.

Unlike a regular observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

LiveData will notify any of your activities that are coming to foreground.